# Short story about an immortality potion given to a man by a witch that only works after 72 hours

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, immortality

I heard a short story a few years ago about a man who threatened a woman (witch) into giving him an immortality potion or something like that, and so she did a while later he died and was buried.

Then he wakes up in his coffin and is mad that she lied to him, but she didn’t lie, she just didn’t tell him that the potion only starts working after like 72 hours.

I think there may have been a bear mauling at some point but I am not too sure about this.